# I'm getting a NaN value when pressing the button in my app, could someone point out why?

Tags: java, android

This is my Java code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private double counter;
private double sum = 0;
private String value;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // handle click
            TextView textGemiddelde = (TextView) 
findViewById(R.id.Gemiddelde);
            textGemiddelde.append(calculate());
        }
    });
}

public double sum() {

    EditText EditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
    double cijfer1 = Double.valueOf(EditText1.getText().toString());

    EditText EditText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText2);
    double cijfer2 = Double.valueOf(EditText2.getText().toString());

    EditText EditText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText3);
    double cijfer3 = Double.valueOf(EditText3.getText().toString());

    EditText EditText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText4);
    double cijfer4 = Double.valueOf(EditText4.getText().toString());

    EditText EditText5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText5);
    double cijfer5 = Double.valueOf(EditText5.getText().toString());

    EditText EditText6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText6);
    double cijfer6 = Double.valueOf(EditText6.getText().toString());

    EditText EditText7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText7);
    double cijfer7 = Double.valueOf(EditText7.getText().toString());

    EditText EditText8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText8);
    double cijfer8 = Double.valueOf(EditText8.getText().toString());

    EditText EditText9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText9);
    double cijfer9 = Double.valueOf(EditText9.getText().toString());

    EditText EditText10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText10);
    double cijfer10 = Double.valueOf(EditText10.getText().toString());


    EditText EditText_1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_1);
    double weging1 = Double.valueOf(EditText_1.getText().toString());

    EditText EditText_2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_2);
    double weging2 = Double.valueOf(EditText_2.getText().toString());

    EditText EditText_3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_3);
    double weging3 = Double.valueOf(EditText_3.getText().toString());

    EditText EditText_4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_4);
    double weging4 = Double.valueOf(EditText_4.getText().toString());

    EditText EditText_5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_5);
    double weging5 = Double.valueOf(EditText_5.getText().toString());

    EditText EditText_6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_6);
    double weging6 = Double.valueOf(EditText_6.getText().toString());

    EditText EditText_7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_7);
    double weging7 = Double.valueOf(EditText_7.getText().toString());

    EditText EditText_8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_8);
    double weging8 = Double.valueOf(EditText_8.getText().toString());

    EditText EditText_9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_9);
    double weging9 = Double.valueOf(EditText_9.getText().toString());

    EditText EditText_10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_10);
    double weging10 = Double.valueOf(EditText_10.getText().toString());


    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText1.getText().toString()) && 
!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText_1.getText().toString())) {
        this.sum += cijfer1 * weging1;
        this.counter++;
    } else {

    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText2.getText().toString()) && 
!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText_2.getText().toString())) {
        this.sum += cijfer2 * weging2;
        this.counter++;
    } else {

    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText3.getText().toString()) && 
!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText_3.getText().toString())) {
        this.sum += cijfer3 * weging3;
        this.counter++;
    } else {

    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText4.getText().toString()) && 
!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText_4.getText().toString())) {
        this.sum += cijfer4 * weging4;
        this.counter++;
    } else {

    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText5.getText().toString()) && 
!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText_5.getText().toString())) {
        this.sum += cijfer5 * weging5;
        this.counter++;
    } else {

    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText6.getText().toString()) && 
!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText_6.getText().toString())) {
        this.sum += cijfer6 * weging6;
        this.counter++;
    } else {

    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText7.getText().toString()) && 
!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText_7.getText().toString())) {
        this.sum += cijfer7 * weging7;
        this.counter++;
    } else {

    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText8.getText().toString()) && 
!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText_8.getText().toString())) {
        this.sum += cijfer8 * weging8;
        this.counter++;
    } else {

    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText9.getText().toString()) && 
!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText_9.getText().toString())) {
        this.sum += cijfer9 * weging9;
        this.counter++;
    } else {

    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText10.getText().toString()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText_10.getText().toString())) {
        this.sum += cijfer10 * weging10;
        this.counter++;
    } else {

    }

    return sum;
}

public double average() {
    return sum / counter;
}

public String calculate() {
    value = String.valueOf(average());
    return value;
}

}
```

This will be my first app so excuse me for messy code. What it basically does is as follows: the app has 10 input fields where you can enter a number and 10 fields to enter the weight of that number. If you click on the bottom button, it will calculate the average of the entered numbers + weight. Currently, when I click on the button, the following gets appended to "textGemiddelde" (which is Dutch for average): NaN. I'd really appreciate it if someone could point out to me why I get this code and not the average of the given numbers + weight.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the range of numbers you are entering? Assuming a valid range, you could try changing `sum / counter` to `sum() / counter`. Also, please learn the importance of `arrays` and `loops` in Java.

Comment: you've probably divided something by zero

Comment: The maxLength of EditText is 4. Thanks for the tip, I'll check both out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NaN occurred because you were trying to compute 0/0. Also, counter is not initialized. I have corrected it. Tell if it works or not.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private double counter = 0;
private double sum = 0;
private String value;
TextView textGemiddelde;
EditText EditText1;
EditText EditText2;
EditText EditText3;
EditText EditText4;
EditText EditText5;
EditText EditText6;
EditText EditText7;
EditText EditText8;
EditText EditText9;
EditText EditText10;
EditText EditText_1;
EditText EditText_2;
EditText EditText_3;
EditText EditText_4;
EditText EditText_5;
EditText EditText_6;
EditText EditText_7;
EditText EditText_8;
EditText EditText_9;
EditText EditText_10;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1);

    EditText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText2);

    EditText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText3);

    EditText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText4);

    EditText5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText5);

    EditText6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText6);

    EditText7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText7);

    EditText8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText8);

    EditText9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText9);

    EditText10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText10);

    EditText_1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_1);

    EditText_2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_2);

    EditText_3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_3);

    EditText_4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_4);

    EditText_5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_5);

    EditText_6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_6);

    EditText_7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_7);

    EditText_8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_8);

    EditText_9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_9);

    EditText_10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_10);

    textGemiddelde = (TextView)
            findViewById(R.id.Gemiddelde);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // handle click
           sum = sum();
            textGemiddelde.append(calculate());
        }
    });
}

public double sum() {

    sum = 0;
    counter = 0;
    double cijfer1 = ParseDouble(EditText1.getText().toString());


    double cijfer2 = ParseDouble(EditText2.getText().toString());


    double cijfer3 = ParseDouble(EditText3.getText().toString());


    double cijfer4 = ParseDouble(EditText4.getText().toString());


    double cijfer5 = ParseDouble(EditText5.getText().toString());


    double cijfer6 = ParseDouble(EditText6.getText().toString());


    double cijfer7 = ParseDouble(EditText7.getText().toString());


    double cijfer8 = ParseDouble(EditText8.getText().toString());


    double cijfer9 = ParseDouble(EditText9.getText().toString());


    double cijfer10 = ParseDouble(EditText10.getText().toString());


    double weging1 = ParseDouble(EditText_1.getText().toString());


    double weging2 = ParseDouble(EditText_2.getText().toString());

    double weging3 = ParseDouble(EditText_3.getText().toString());

    double weging4 = ParseDouble(EditText_4.getText().toString());

    double weging5 = ParseDouble(EditText_5.getText().toString());

    double weging6 = ParseDouble(EditText_6.getText().toString());

    double weging7 = ParseDouble(EditText_7.getText().toString());

    double weging8 = ParseDouble(EditText_8.getText().toString());

    double weging9 = ParseDouble(EditText_9.getText().toString());

    double weging10 = ParseDouble(EditText_10.getText().toString());


    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText1.getText().toString()) &&
            !TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText_1.getText().toString())) {
        this.sum += cijfer1 * weging1;
        this.counter++;
    } else {

    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText2.getText().toString()) &&
            !TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText_2.getText().toString())) {
        this.sum += cijfer2 * weging2;
        this.counter++;
    } else {

    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText3.getText().toString()) &&
            !TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText_3.getText().toString())) {
        this.sum += cijfer3 * weging3;
        this.counter++;
    } else {

    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText4.getText().toString()) &&
            !TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText_4.getText().toString())) {
        this.sum += cijfer4 * weging4;
        this.counter++;
    } else {

    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText5.getText().toString()) &&
            !TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText_5.getText().toString())) {
        this.sum += cijfer5 * weging5;
        this.counter++;
    } else {

    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText6.getText().toString()) &&
            !TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText_6.getText().toString())) {
        this.sum += cijfer6 * weging6;
        this.counter++;
    } else {

    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText7.getText().toString()) &&
            !TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText_7.getText().toString())) {
        this.sum += cijfer7 * weging7;
        this.counter++;
    } else {

    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText8.getText().toString()) &&
            !TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText_8.getText().toString())) {
        this.sum += cijfer8 * weging8;
        this.counter++;
    } else {

    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText9.getText().toString()) &&
            !TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText_9.getText().toString())) {
        this.sum += cijfer9 * weging9;
        this.counter++;
    } else {

    }

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText10.getText().toString()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(EditText_10.getText().toString())) {
        this.sum += cijfer10 * weging10;
        this.counter++;
    } else {

    }

    return sum;
}

public double average() {
    if(couter == 0) return -1;
    return sum / counter;
}

public String calculate() {
    value = String.valueOf(average());
    return value;
}
double ParseDouble(String strNumber) {
    if (strNumber != null && strNumber.length() > 0) {
        try {
            return Double.parseDouble(strNumber);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return -1;   // or some value to mark this field is wrong. or make a function validates field first ...
        }
    }
    else return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, it isn't working yet because EditText1 t/m EditText10 and EditText_1 t/m EditText_10 get the error "Cannot resolve EditText(x)". Maybe EditText EditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1); and the others shouldn't be placed in the protected void class, or am I wrong?

Comment: I have modified my answer

Comment: thanks for the help, but for some reason the same error still occurs. EditText1 t/m EditText10 and EditText_1 t/m EditText_10 still get the error "Cannot resolve symbol ..."

Comment: have you assigned the id's in activitymain.xml?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help! The error is gone now but for some reason the app just crashes now when I click on the button.

Comment: 08-14 18:31:20.491 23051-23051/com.firstapp.rekenmachine E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.firstapp.rekenmachine, PID: 23051
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1071)
        at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:511)
        at com.firstapp.rekenmachine.MainActivity.sum(MainActivity.java:109)
        at com.firstapp.rekenmachine.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:94)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612)

Comment: at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22288)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)

Comment: Thank you very much I'll test it now and reply back soon!

Comment: Thank you very much, the app is working now, this fixed the NaN error! I'll study your code and check why this works and mine doesn't, again thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't call the `sum()` method and your variables `counter` is not initialized.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to change those, but didn't I initialize the counter by giving it a value of private int counter; in the main body and adding to the counter in the if else statements in the sum() method?

Comment: counter gets initialized to 0. Before the sum() method is called sum is also zero. Division of 0/0 will give you NaN. Call sum() in calculate method and you should be all right. But of course it will be fine only during the first click. On the second and subsequent clicks, your average will be divided by 2 and so on. Reset the counter and sum in sum(). Rename sum to average, remove sum and counter members. Declare sum and counter as local variables in method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call sum() method so that the sum and counter variables have the values. In the current code, they are 0 as the sum() method is not called. So, 0/0 returns NaN.
Also, you need to reset the values of sum and counter every time the button is clicked. Or else these values will get added up every time as these are the field variables.
Also, you don't have to use findViewById every time in the sum() method.
Just initialize it once in the onCreate and it will serve the purpose, as this operation is the heavy one.
For quick fix change the average methods by:

```
public double average() {
    sum = 0;
    counter = 0;
    sum();
    return sum / counter;
}
```

This will work.

But to make the code neat and good, you can write the class as:

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private double counter;
private double sum = 0;
private String value;
private EditText mEditText1;
private EditText mEditText2;
private EditText mEditText3;
private EditText mEditText4;
private EditText mEditText5;
private EditText mEditText6;
private EditText mEditText7;
private EditText mEditText8;
private EditText mEditText9;
private EditText mEditText10;
private EditText mEditText_1;
private EditText mEditText_2;
private EditText mEditText_3;
private EditText mEditText_4;
private EditText mEditText_5;
private EditText mEditText_6;
private EditText mEditText_7;
private EditText mEditText_8;
private EditText mEditText_9;
private EditText mEditText_10;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
    mEditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
    mEditText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText2);
    mEditText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText3);
    mEditText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText4);
    mEditText5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText5);
    mEditText6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText6);
    mEditText7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText7);
    mEditText8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText8);
    mEditText9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText9);
    mEditText10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText10);

    mEditText_1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_1);
    mEditText_2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_2);
    mEditText_3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_3);
    mEditText_4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_4);
    mEditText_5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_5);
    mEditText_6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_6);
    mEditText_7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_7);
    mEditText_8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_8);
    mEditText_9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_9);
    mEditText_10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_10);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // handle click
            TextView textGemiddelde = (TextView)
                    findViewById(R.id.Gemiddelde);
            textGemiddelde.append(calculate());
        }
    });
}

public double sum() {

    sum = 0;
    counter = 0;

    double cijfer1 = Double.valueOf(mEditText1.getText().toString());
    double cijfer2 = Double.valueOf(mEditText2.getText().toString());
    double cijfer3 = Double.valueOf(mEditText3.getText().toString());
    double cijfer4 = Double.valueOf(mEditText4.getText().toString());
    double cijfer5 = Double.valueOf(mEditText5.getText().toString());
    double cijfer6 = Double.valueOf(mEditText6.getText().toString());
    double cijfer7 = Double.valueOf(mEditText7.getText().toString());
    double cijfer8 = Double.valueOf(mEditText8.getText().toString());
    double cijfer9 = Double.valueOf(mEditText9.getText().toString());
    double cijfer10 = Double.valueOf(mEditText10.getText().toString());

    double weging1 = Double.valueOf(mEditText_1.getText().toString());
    double weging2 = Double.valueOf(mEditText_2.getText().toString());
    double weging3 = Double.valueOf(mEditText_3.getText().toString());
    double weging4 = Double.valueOf(mEditText_4.getText().toString());
    double weging5 = Double.valueOf(mEditText_5.getText().toString());
    double weging6 = Double.valueOf(mEditText_6.getText().toString());
    double weging7 = Double.valueOf(mEditText_7.getText().toString());
    double weging8 = Double.valueOf(mEditText_8.getText().toString());
    double weging9 = Double.valueOf(mEditText_9.getText().toString());
    double weging10 = Double.valueOf(mEditText_10.getText().toString());


    if (cijfer1 != 0 && weging1 != 0) {
        this.sum += cijfer1 * weging1;
        this.counter++;
    }

    if (cijfer2 != 0 && weging2 != 0) {
        this.sum += cijfer2 * weging2;
        this.counter++;
    }

    if (cijfer3 != 0 && weging3 != 0) {
        this.sum += cijfer3 * weging3;
        this.counter++;
    }

    if (cijfer4 != 0 && weging4 != 0) {
        this.sum += cijfer4 * weging4;
        this.counter++;
    }

    if (cijfer5 != 0 && weging5 != 0) {
        this.sum += cijfer5 * weging5;
        this.counter++;
    }

    if (cijfer6 != 0 && weging6 != 0) {
        this.sum += cijfer6 * weging6;
        this.counter++;
    }

    if (cijfer7 != 0 && weging7 != 0) {
        this.sum += cijfer7 * weging7;
        this.counter++;
    }

    if (cijfer8 != 0 && weging8 != 0) {
        this.sum += cijfer8 * weging8;
        this.counter++;
    }

    if (cijfer9 != 0 && weging9 != 0) {
        this.sum += cijfer9 * weging9;
        this.counter++;
    }

    if (cijfer10 != 0 && weging10 != 0) {
        this.sum += cijfer10 * weging10;
        this.counter++;
    }
    return sum;
}

public String calculate() {
    sum = 0;
    counter = 0;
    sum();
    if (counter != 0)
        value = String.valueOf(sum / counter);
    else
        value = "Invalid Input";
    return value;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this quick fix change unfortunately doesn't work. Once I click on the button the app crashes now.

Comment: It is because you did not enter anything in the counter edittexts. Please try after entering something in the edittexts.

Comment: For more info, please go to the calculate method in the lower code section. If the counter =0, then simply show some error to the user.